# Chrome Custom Tabs hide address bar

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

I am developing a widget that customers can integrate into their apps. Their users must authenticate themselves (via OAuth). Therefore, it's preferable that my customers use Chrome Custom Tabs so that the user is likely logged in with the OAuth provider (eg. Facebook).

Is there some way to hide the address bar for a Chrome Custom Tab? The URL isn't really relevant to the end user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to hide the address bar. It is critically important for the user to be able to tell which authority they are talking to when they are visiting a website, in particular when they are authenticating. This saves a lot of users from phishing.

Comment: is it possible to lock the address bar, pardon me if it dumb question (i'm new in this field)